# Python pandas read a csv from one column then seperate columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv that needs seperation based on number of issues, and im currently getting an error with my code

```
 dfcleancsv = pd.read_csv('InitialQuerydataOpen.csv', sep=",")


ValueError: Expected 1 fields in line 1609, saw 55
```

What I have

```
Column1 Column2
1583    FIT-491
1584    FIT-4276,"TC 1140.0024, 1140.0025, 1140.0026, 1140.0179, 1140.018"
```

What I want

```
Column1 Column 2    Column3   Column4  Column5    Column6  Column7
1583    FIT-491
1584    FIT-4276  1140.0024 1140.0025 1140.0026 1140.0179 1140.018
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
        data = {i:txt.strip().split(',') for i,txt in enumerate(f.readlines())}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
print(df)

## -- End pasted text --
      0          1          2          3          4          5         6
0  1583  FIT-491         None       None       None       None      None
1  1584   FIT-4276  1140.0024  1140.0025  1140.0026  1140.0179  1140.018
```